# Bash 4.4 change color vi mode

Tags: bash, command-line, colors, prompt, inputrc

I am using

```
+~ $ bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

and added to my `~/.bashrc`

```
 set -o vi
```

and in my `/etc/inputrc`

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[1;31m\2:\1\e[0m\2"
```

however the color remains the same when I enter command mode. Could some one resolve this issue. only the leading character changes from `+` to `:`

Comment: Testing this in `bash` release 5.0.18, the prompt changes from a white `(ins)` in insert mode to a red `:` in normal mode. I believe this is what the intention was. It's unclear whether this still is an issue for the user asking the original question. I'm closing this as "needs more details" for the time being.